# load dynamically data in grid kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

As you can see in the picture this is a kendo grid that gets the data from the database and do the sorting, paging and grouping and right now it has been grouped by. My record are a lot, they're more than 2-3 millions and because of this reason I can not send all my data to the grid so first the I send a request to database and then I receive the paged, sorted and group by response back from the server and everything works great but sometimes there might be only 2 set of grouped data but inside these two there might be millions of data so this is what I did, I just show the name of the groups with no child data. My problem is that when someone clicks on a group, I want to open up it's nodes and show the related data. but I didn't find any method in kendo to show the nodes' data that is present inside a datasource in its related node.

Comment: Sorry mate, but can't get you. Probably because of your little bit bad English :)

Comment: You can use [`detailInit`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-detailInit) parameter, [check this out](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy). Also, you forgot to add the image to the post.